# getElementById returns undefines

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm trying to write to a div using javascript. It takes input from the user and I want it to write to the div. The input is html code for a twitter widget. It returns undefined and I don't understand why.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
      <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Cheese</h2>
          <p>A seriously awesome food</p>
             <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="200x200" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; position:relative; top:-10px;" src="Pictures/cheese.jpeg"/>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="cheese.html" role="button style-"position-top:10px;">Learn more »</a></p></div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Reply</h2>
          <p>Reply to a twitter tweet!</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?">Reply</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Post</h2>
          <button onclick="myFunction()">Enter Code</button>
          **<script>
          function myFunction(){
          var x;
          var code=prompt("Please enter your html code.");
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=x;

          }

          </script>**
          <div id="test">

</div>

          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You've set `#test.innerHTML` to `undefined`. There's just `var x;`. How to fix, depends on, what you want to show on the `div`.

Comment: getElementById never returns undefined. If the element is not found then it returns null, but in your case it should find it. Please describe your problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare **two** variables in your function: "x" and "code". You assign something to one and then use the other.

```
      var x;
      var code=prompt("Please enter your html code.");
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=x;
```

Thus, "x" is never defined, and "code" is never used.

Comment: thanks, i can't believe i missed that. I dont even know why I had the variable x.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your scripts below the div(id is 'test') or inside the window.onload function that your dom would be ready for insertion of data.

```
function myFunction(){
    var x;
    var code=prompt("Please enter your html code.");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=x;
}
```

Comment: Did you even have a look at the OP's code? It doesn't matter where the function I defined because it's only called once the DOM is ready anyway.

Comment: Furthermore, if the function really was put in a onload handler, it would be local to that handler, and the inline button event handler couldn't find the function. (And to whoever upvoted this: you didn't seem to have read the code either...)